# Python - win32con.FLASHW_* flags

Tags: python, win32gui

G'day,
At his link http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32gui__FlashWindowEx_meth.html there is the documentation for win32gui.FlashWindowEx(), which I have managed to get working with

```
import win32gui as w
a = w.GetForegroundWindow() #just get the handler/ID for the current window
w.FlashWindowEx(a,0,5,1000) #many variations of the 5,1000 have been tried
```

but all that happens in the Windows 7 taskbar is the icon gets the golden background, not flashing, so my question is, does anyone know about the win32con.FLASHW_* flags the documentation makes mention of, perhaps a link to more info about them?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more information on the Visual Basic version of the `FlashWindowEx` function available  on Microsoft's support side at ["How to use FlashWindowEx to Notify a User from Visual Basic"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254339).

That page includes a list of the `FLASHW_*` flags.

Answer (score 0):

refer: http://guangboo.org/2013/05/14/wxpython-flashwindow-using-win32api

```
from ctypes import *
import win32con 
import win32gui as w
cur_window = w.GetForegroundWindow() #just get the handler/ID for the current window

class FLASHWINFO(Structure):
        _fields_ = [('cbSize', c_uint),
                ('hwnd', c_uint),
                ('dwFlags', c_uint),
                ('uCount', c_uint),
                ('dwTimeout', c_uint)]

def flash(hwnd):
        '''Flash a window with caption and tray.'''
        info = FLASHWINFO(0, hwnd, win32con.FLASHW_ALL | win32con.FLASHW_TIMERNOFG, 0, 0)
        info.cbSize = sizeof(info)
        FlashWindowEx(byref(info))

flash(cur_window)
```